# Need to set css only for single component

Tags: angular

I am trying to make some CSS changes in my component.

```
.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
          .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
               max-height: 420px !important;
}
```

But changes are not reflecting in my application . But when i do the same changes in
styles.scss file changes are reflecting but they are reflecting in all components.

Can anyone please help me with this how can i make changes from styles.css to a particular component?

Comment: do the changes in the component's css file like app.component.css

Comment: yes I have done this but the changes are not reflecting

Comment: remove the changes from your styles.css file and do the change only in your  required component

Answer (score 2):

so In my solution, you need to write the CSS styling on style.css but by defining another class or encapsulate it. for example `<div> <ng-select class="ngdrop"></ng-select></div>`

and on the style.css

```
.ngdrop{

 .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
      .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
           max-height: 420px !important;
```

}
}

be sure your name  is correct on a defined class

Answer (score 1):

**https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation** - read this

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```